# Specifying a suggested package in a Python Package

Tags: python, python-import, python-packaging

I'm looking to add a *conditional* dependency for a python package inside a new Python package. If the package is already installed, then we want to allow for features to be used. Otherwise, we want to ignore the package. The reason for having a *soft* dependency is some packages likely would not be used by certain users and, thus, we would want to avoid installing them.

Reading through:

https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/

There is only the option to specify hard requirements, e.g. [`install_requires`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#install-requires). Is there a way to specify a soft dependency similar to *R*'s [`Suggest`](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file) field in the `DESCRIPTION` file?

Otherwise, I think safe guarding function calls would be required with soft errors along the lines of:

```py
def demo_function():
   if load_package("numpy", "np"):
     return np.array([1])
   return [1]
```

where `load_package()` uses the following helper functions:

```py
def check_installed(name):
  import importlib.util
  
  spec = importlib.util.find_spec(name)
  if spec is None:
      return False
  
  return True


def load_package(name, alias, soft_error = True):
  import importlib.util
  
  if check_installed(name):
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    if alias is None:
      alias = name
    sys.modules[alias] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  else: 
    if hard_error:
      return False
    else: 
      raise AssertionError(f"Please install `{name}` package to use this function.")
  
  return True
```

Comment: To check if a library is importable, typically a `try: import lib; except ImportError: print ("Suggest installing 'LibName'")` should be good enough, no immediate need to over-complicate things. -- And no, there is no dedicated way to specify "suggested dependencies". If I were you I would use optional extras for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can `try:` when importing, or use contextlib. To check whether the import succeeded, look in sys.modules:

```
from contextlib import suppress
with suppress(ModuleNotFoundError):
    # noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
    import numpy

import sys

if 'numpy' in sys.modules:
    print("numpy was imported")
```